# Position:fixed not working

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page with the following content -

```
<div class="sidebar">
    Some content here....
</div>
<div class="content">
    content here too...
</div>
```

I want the .sidebar to be `position:fixed`, But not the .content. Here is what I have tried in CSS -

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;} 
.sidebar{
   background:rgb(24, 33, 61);
   text-align: right;
   height: 100% !important;
   width:30%;
   postion:fixed;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   bottom:0;
   padding:1em;
   color:white;
 }
 .content{
    width:70%;
   font-size:1.1em;
   font-weight:normal;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   padding:2em;
 }
```

Basically, I want to reproduce [this](http://purecss.io/layouts/blog/).
But what I'm getting now looks perfect at first glance, but when you scroll down, the .sidebar doesn't move with you, it stays at the same place.
[Codepen demonstration](http://codepen.io/saivineet89/pen/yDwGa)

How can I make it work?

Comment: You have typo in the css code. It is `position` not `postion`.

Comment: Don’t hate yourself. Just use the [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) in future.

Comment: @JezenThomas, [Okay.](http://fuuu.us/168.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct the typo -

```
position:fixed;
```

not -

```
postion:fixed;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your position spelling. Please replace like:

```
position:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to apply `position` to sidebar div. Not `postion`

**CSS CODE:**

```
.sidebar{
   background:rgb(24, 33, 61);
   text-align: right;
   height: 100% !important;
   width:30%;
   postion:fixed;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   bottom:0;
   padding:1em;
   color:white;
    position: fixed;
 }
 .content{
    width:70%;
   font-size:1.1em;
   font-weight:normal;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   padding:2em;
    height: 800px;
 }
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/eg23c/1/

Comment: You could have just told me that there was a typo. Sorry, I'm just +1 ing you, not marking you correct, as a commenter told me before you.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iihcg)**

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.sidebar{
   background:rgb(24, 33, 61);
   text-align: right;
   height: 100% !important;
   width:30%;
   postion:fixed;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   bottom:0;
   padding:1em;
   color:white;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
 }
 .content{
    width:60%;
   font-size:1.1em;
   font-weight:normal;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   padding:2em;
 }
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36160/discussion-between-divya-bhalodiya-and-fags)

Answer (score 0):

Use following css :

```
 *{
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .sidebar{
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #18213D;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-left: -25%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
     }
     .content{
        width:70%;
       font-size:1.1em;
       font-weight:normal;
       position: absolute;
       top:0;
       right:0;
       padding:2em;
     }
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/SC5ET/